# Assertion Failed - crash on Unity-Xbox

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unity-game-engine, xbox360

I keep getting this error in xbWatson after Unity-Xbox crashes:

```
Assertion failed: pDestination, file c:\program files (x86)\microsoft xbox 360 sdk\include\xbox\xnamathconvert.inl, line 7124
```

Assuming I know almost nothing about c++, what does this error typically mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the error is that the programmer put in a check (called *assertion*) to see if everything was according to their expectations and that check failed.  If you can figure out where `pDestination` is coming from (most likely have to guess based on its value), you might be able to do something about it -- cannot tell from the error itself

Comment: ah, i understand. I think what I am seeing happen is that the function being called has an out value. The function runs the out value through XMASSERT and errors out when it is null. Why would it matter if the variable being used for the out is null at first?

Comment: @fraggleRockz - null values are often sources of problems as they represent "nothing", and as such you cannot perform any operations on them, thus the program is blocked from proceeding as anticipated